# Why does while loop in python not end?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, boolean, pyautogui

I am trying to stop the loop after 1 go through, and the next time through the loop i want it to hit the other button, but right now its stuck in the first if bid_balance%2 == 0

```
def market_search(self):
    bid_balance = 0
    player_found = False
    
    while player_found is False:
        if self.stopped:
            break

        print("BOT looking for players .....")
        if (bid_balance%2 == 0):
            # Edit bid price
            pyautogui.moveTo(1300, 798)
            sleep(0.500)
            #pyautogui.click()
        
        else:
            pyautogui.moveTo(828, 798)
            sleep(0.500)
            #pyautogui.click()
            
            
        # Serching knap
        pyautogui.moveTo(1622, 1281)
        sleep(0.500)
        #pyautogui.click()

        
        # time for Site to load
        sleep(self.SITLOADINGTIME_SECONDS)
        bid_balance += 1
        player_found = True
    return player_found
```

The multithreading and the logic controller for the bot

```
    # threading methods
def update_target(self, rectangles):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.rectangles = rectangles
    self.lock.release()

def update_screenshot(self, screenshot):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.screenshot = screenshot
    self.lock.release()

def start(self):
    self.stopped = False
    t = Thread(target=self.run)
    t.start()

def stop(self):
    self.stopped = True


# main logic controller
def run(self):
    while not self.stopped:
        if self.state == BotState.INITIALIZING:
            # do no bot actions until the startup waiting period is complete
            if time() > self.timestamp + self.INITIALIZING_SECONDS:
                
                # start searching when the waiting period is over
                self.lock.acquire()
                self.state = BotState.SEARCHING
                self.lock.release()


        elif self.state == BotState.SEARCHING:
            # Call the market searching function
            self.market_search()

            # start buying when the waiting period is over
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.state = BotState.BUYING
            self.lock.release()

        elif self.state == BotState.BUYING:
            # Call the buyer when serching is over
            self.buyer()

            # Start seaching again 
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.state = BotState.SEARCHING
            self.lock.release()
```

error i recive:

```
BOT looking for players .....
BOT looking for players .....
BOT looking for players .....
BOT looking for players .....
BOT looking for players .....
BOT looking for players .....
Exception in thread Thread-3 (run):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\nickl\Desktop\Code\Projekt Fifa 23\bot.py", line 198, in run
    self.market_search()
  File "c:\Users\nickl\Desktop\Code\Projekt Fifa 23\bot.py", line 73, in market_search
    pyautogui.moveTo(1622, 1281)
  File "C:\Users\nickl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 597, in wrapper
    failSafeCheck()
  File "C:\Users\nickl\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1722, in failSafeCheck
    raise FailSafeException(
pyautogui.FailSafeException: PyAutoGUI fail-safe triggered from mouse moving to a corner of the screen. To disable this fail-safe, set pyautogui.FAILSAFE to False. DISABLING FAIL-SAFE IS NOT RECOMMENDED.
Screen Capture FPS: 53
Done.
```

I cant stop it either, even thoug i made a stop fucntion under the main python file, so i have to use the Fail Safe Exception from pyautogui

Comment: About the error: is this coordinate correct? (1622, 1281)

Comment: I ran your code myself and was not able to recreate this issue.

Comment: @EdsonPassos Yes the coordinate is correct just double checked

Comment: @JRose You could run the loop without it being stuck?

Comment: I see no evidence that the loop doesn't end. To me it looks like you're calling the function multiple times.

Comment: I am using multithreading, like this has this anything to do with it maybe?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I am not sure i follow, can you show me?

Comment: @NicklasJensen copy your function into a separate file as a standalone program and try running it. Are you running multiple instances of market search and confusing that for the loop running multiple times?

Comment: @JRose it might run multiple times i am not sure, but then thats my problem, and i cant fix that either :(

Comment: @NicklasJensen why is it a bug if `market_search` runs multiple times? In your current while loop that is the logic. Set `self.stopped` to True after it runs once if you want to check this.

Comment: @JRose but i am locking it and realising the lock arent i? Dosent that mean it should only run when the player_found = false, and when i put it to true, it shouldent?

Comment: @JRose and i am setting the bot.state to run that specefik thing, and then switching to another state?

Comment: @NicklasJensen You are saying that when you do `player_found = False` **before** `while player_found is False:` the print statement is still triggering?

Comment: @JRose Yeah its never getting to the part where it sets the player_found to true, so it stops running that part of the code, and then switches state to another bot.state like elif self.state == BotState.BUYING: